# Inheritance Robot Race that doesn't update array

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, return

I am working on a program that is suppose to have 3 different Robots racing on a track. The track is suppose to be 100 in length. I have just learned inheritance and still trying to understand how to connect data members from one .h to another. When I run my program, nothing happens when I call any of my Robots. I will show one of them as an example. Can you explain how to make their movements update the race 2D array?

**robotRace.h**

```
#ifndef ROBOTRACE_H
#define ROBOTRACE_H

using namespace std;

class robotRace {

      public:

       robotRace (); //constructor
       static const int rows = 5;
       static const int columns = 100;

       protected:

       int race[rows][columns]; //initial base for race floor

};// end superclass robotRace that should do no movement

#endif
```

**robotRace.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "robotRace.h"

using namespace std;

robotRace :: robotRace() {

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)

      for (int j= 0; j<columns; j++)

       race[i][j] = ' ';

}//end constructor
```

This is one of the Robots and their functions to update array. Not sure how to make it work.

**FunctionRobot.h**

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONROBOT_H
#define FUNCTIONROBOT_H
#include "robotRace.h"

using namespace std;

class FunctionRobot : public robotRace{

    public:
    FunctionRobot();
    int position(int);
    void print();
    protected:


};

#endif
```

**FunctionRobot.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FunctionRobot.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

FunctionRobot :: FunctionRobot (): robotRace() {

    int initPos =0;
    race[initPos][0] = '*';
    cout <<"Initial position of Function Robot is at begin of race."<<endl;

}

int FunctionRobot :: position(int place=0){

    // log with a base 2 needs to be divided by the "x"
    // below is the Robots formula to determine each of their movements
    double x = ( 2 * (log(place)/log(2)));
    return (int) x;

}

void FunctionRobot :: print(){

    for (int i;i=0; i<100; i++)
       for (int j;j=0; j<1; j++)
            race[position()][j];

}
```

this is my main file as requested. This is basic format. I am hoping to make the while loop more practical so that the user doesn't have to keep entering 1.
There is also no error coming from my code. It runs just shows nothing.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "robotRace.h"
#include "FunctionRobot.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int userInput;

  cout << "Welcome to the Robot Race of the year!" << endl;
  cout << "For our contestants we have the amazing three!" << endl;
  cout << "The contestants are Robots F, R and U" << endl;
  cout << "Let the games begin! \n\n";

  cout << "Enter 1 to begin. " << endl;
  cin >> userInput;

  FunctionRobot functionObj;
//functionObj.position();
//functionObj.print();
  cout << "Ready... Set... Go!!" << endl;

  while (userInput == 1) {

    functionObj.position(4);
    functionObj.print();

  }  //end while

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your code? Maybe you should provide the main too.

Comment: Have you used debugger to check which line is having problem? Also, if something is not updating properly or according to the expectation, debugger should be able to reveal what goes on at that line.

Comment: There is no errors showing on my code. I am also unfamiliar with your comment of "debugger". I am using putty so I have never seen a debugger?

Comment: Your robot position function is slightly dodgy. Chances are that due to precision loss, you will get wrong positions in your position array and have wrong information.

Comment: I have 4 for position because he is suppose to begin at index 4 when race begins

Comment: @AlyssaCooke     Does "gdb" ring a bell? I am assuming you are using command line GCC

Comment: can you explain precision loss a little more?

Comment: @AlyssaCooke check my answer (I am updating now)

Comment: our class has never used that before so no it doesn't ring a bell. But since I have no errors showing in the compiler... wouldn't a debugger not make sense?

Comment: @AlyssaCooke When someone suggests an edit on your post, you should guarentee that it improved the post. In your case, you've approved an edit that removed the main.cpp code from the post. While the other changes seemed to improve your post, you should never accept an edit like this. Or you can choose "Aprove and edit" to add the removed part. Or, you can leave it as it is and someone will take care of the edit : )

Comment: This was the first time someone made an edit. I saw the title change and didn't realize that it cause my main to change.

Comment: @AlyssaCooke I'm not criticizing or "pointing a finger". I commented so you could understand what happened to your main.cpp and so you could learn something about suggested edits. It's natural to make a few mistakes along the way : )

Comment: ya I see now what happened. Thanks. I will just play with my code for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print()` goes out of bounds:

```
void FunctionRobot :: print(){

    for (int i; i<100; i++)
     for (int j; j<1; j++)
            race[position()][j];

}
```

`j` is not initialized. You could try `int j = 0` for a start. Similar for `i`.

Moreover you know that this function is named PRINT but doesn't PRINT ANYTHING, actually it doesn't do anything but calling `position()`.

---

```
int FunctionRobot :: position(int place=0){

    // log with a base 2 needs to be divided by the "x"
    // below is the Robots formula to determine each of their movements
    double x = ( 2 * (log(place)/log(2))); <-------- now x is a double
    return (int) x;                        <-------- now x is an integer, are you sure about that?

}
```

Loss of precision happens here. Let's say that `x` is assigned a value of 3.14. Then you cast it (the cast would happen automatically since the return type of the function is also an int) into an integer, thus it will be converted to 3, thus you loss precision.

---

About `main.cpp`

You call the user to input 1 and then you have:

```
  while (userInput == 1) {

    functionObj.position(4);
    functionObj.print();

  }  //end while
```

but `userInput` is not going to be modified, thus you are running into a non-ending loop.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize I didn't update the i and j to =0. and yes I want it returned as an int because its going by 0,1,2,... as it moves "steps". I'm trying to keep all robots increments as whole numbers because the rest are enforced to be ints.

Comment: I updated the =0 part. The program still runs to the "Get ready..set..go" and just sits after... program does run further nor stop

Comment: Well I don't know how's your main looks like.

Comment: This is my problem to be exact. I called the function in my print so that it would update the print. I don't know how to connect the return value from my function to my print. The print function is really my concern. And the while loop: I left it that way to simply see if anything would print once. I know I have to cin again at the end.

Comment: Well, I fixed the code you had..You could add `cout` to your `print()`. I mean what else do you want me to do? :) I suggest you accept the answer, sit and think what we discussed, modify your code, test it again and again and then, if needed come back for a **new** question in Stackoverflow, because this one gets a bit too broad, which is off-topic. @AlyssaCooke